# How to ask "does it come with chips/rice/potatoes?" in a restaurant

Tags: question

This has been bothering me for a while now when I order food in restaurants. Would I just be able to say

> "Kommt es mit Reis dazu?"

or does that sound odd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > "Kommt es mit Reis dazu?"
>
> or does that sound odd?

Yes, that sounds odd. The waiter will probably understand what you mean, but it's not usual.

Generally, we call *rice*, *potatoes*, *chips* **Beilage**. So you have several options:

1. Ask

   > Was gibt es als Beilage, Reis?<sup>1</sup>
2. Ask for it specifically

   > Kann ich Reis statt Kartoffeln als Beilage haben?
3. Ask unspecifically, and let the waiter enumerate

   > Welche Beilagen gibt es zum Steak?

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Sounds a little bit impolite for me. Probably forgiven with a non native speaker.</sub>

Comment: Or simply: *Kann ich Reis statt Kartoffeln **dazu** haben/bekommen?*

Answer (score 3):

1. Ist da Reis dabei?
2. Gibt es dazu Reis?

Während πάντα ῥεῖ gute, hochsprachige Alternativen aufzeigt, gibt sie keine Übersetzung, die sehr eng an der Frage bleibt.

Meine Sätze funktionieren auch mit Salat und Hammelfleisch.